# Windows Mobile - Way to invert compact framework controls

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, controls

I have a screen in my windows mobile app that I is intended for another person than the user to look at and interact with (it is a signature screen).

There is a few edit boxes and such on that screen.  Is there any way to make them display upside down?

If so I would love to hear how.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the controls (except the signature) purely for viewing (i.e. interaction is not needed)?  If so, I'd be inclined to just take a [screen shot](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/11/ScreenCaptureInTheCompactFramework.aspx), [rotate that bitmap](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/faf52bf4-aa80-38c4-86a7-819b4d7225fd.htm), [draw it to the Form's background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground.aspx) and then put the signature control on top of that.

Comment: Alas, OnPaintBackground is not supported in the compact framework. :(

Comment: No, OnPaintBackground certain *is* supported.  I use it all the time.  You're overriding it in the Form, right?

Comment: You are right.  I was looking for it as an event.  My bad.  I probably should have used `SystemSettings.ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Angle180;` for this.  But I did not know about it till I was almost done.  Now that it is done, this way lets the main user keep the menu and title bar facing them, so it is a bit better.  Thanks for the help (on this and other questions).